# How with tflileInputExcel in talend

Tags: talend

I want to process multiple files one by one to merge them into one excel file(xlsx) using tfilelist so I proceeded like the screenshot but I'm getting these errors:

```
            For input string: "N_Vol"
            For input string: "N_Vol"
 Exception in component tFileInputExcel_1
 org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidOperationException: 
 Can't open the specified file: 'C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Data2 - 
 Copie\~$S_1.xlsx'
 at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init> 
(ZipPackage.java:112)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:224)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:186)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.openPackage(POIXMLDocument.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:296)
at tunisair.lig_0_1.lig.tFileList_1Process(lig.java:913)
at tunisair.lig_0_1.lig.runJobInTOS(lig.java:2053)
at tunisair.lig_0_1.lig.main(lig.java:1910)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.ZipHelper.openZipFile(ZipHelper.java:174)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:110)
```

This is my job.

[image: this is my job]

Comment: Post the code which gives you tis error.

Comment: Can you please show us the setting you did in excel input component

Answer (score 0):

here is my tfileexcelinput parameters
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qOuD.jpg][1]

Answer (score 0):

As said somewhere else ;) it seems there is a problem with 'C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Data2 - Copie\~$S_1.xlsx'.
Is this file in your input folder?
Are you able to open it with Excel?
Also, I saw you've selected the option to read all sheets in the Excel files. Are they all based on the same schema?

Comment: I'd also add that the excel file must not be open in Excel, otherwise the job can't access it (I've seen that mistake often) ;)

Answer (score 0):

yes all files have the same schema  and  this file is not on my input folder and i dont know why he reads it and not reading the files in my input folder?